# How to set Logarithmic Y-Axis in telerik RadHtmlChart

Tags: c#, telerik

Islogarithmic property is not supported in Radhtmlchart.

How can i set nonlinear scale for Y axis.Is there any way around?

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported, but someone has just already created a ticket for this: [CHECK HERE](http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/108/Feedback/Details/50627-add-logarithmic-y-axis-in-radhtmlchart)